# MySQL query to replace spaces in a column with underscores

Tags: mysql, replace, space

I have a MySQL database table 'photos' with a column 'filename'. 
I need to replace the spaces in the filename column values with underscores.
Is it possible with a single/multiple query? If so how?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use the [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function :

> `REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)`
>
> Returns the string `str` with all
>   occurrences of the string `from_str`
>   replaced by the string `to_str`.
>   
> `REPLACE()` performs a case-sensitive
>   match when searching for `from_str`.

So, to replace all occurences of a character by another one in all lines of a table, something like this should do :

```
update photos set filename = replace(filename, ' ', '_');
```

ie, you search for ' ' in the column `filename` and use '_' instead ; and put the result back into `filename`.

Comment: Worked like a charm.+1

Answer (score 7):

```
update photos set filename = replace(filename,' ', '_');
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.+1