# Removing and replacing whitespace to hyphens in an html description in mysql in img tags

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

There are several image tags in a html description row there is a problem as the images uploaded had some spaces in between

for ex:

```
<div class="colUnitImg">
                <img src="{images_home}images/corsair/VENGEANCE-8GB-DDR4-C16-RAM/description/heat spreader.jpg" alt="Heat Spreader">
</div>
```

I want to change this into

```
<div class="colUnitImg">
                <img src="{images_home}images/corsair/VENGEANCE-8GB-DDR4-C16-RAM/description/heat-spreader.jpg" alt="Heat Spreader">
            </div>
```

as you can see the image file name has a space and i want it to turn the white space in hyphen

I have run a unix based that recursively did the changes in the file name on the server but I want a mysql query to make the changes in the mysql table.

```
UPDATE product_description
SET description = REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '(?<=<img[^>]*src="[^"]*[/{][^"/]*) (?=[^"]*"[^>]*>)', '-')
WHERE description REGEXP '<img[^>]src="[^"]*[/{][^"/] [^"]*"[^>]*>';
```

I used this but my version of mysql is 5.6 and I dont have admin rights to update the version.

I also did some tweeking with the SUBSTRING_INDEX function in mysql but it deleted the image tags in the row.

I just want the file name white space to be replaced with hyphens

Comment: Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806949/mysql-query-to-replace-spaces-in-a-column-with-underscores

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL query to replace spaces in a column with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806949/mysql-query-to-replace-spaces-in-a-column-with-underscores)

Comment: @Yogendra please read the question the answer you sent will replace any whitespace to -

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE
product_description
SET
description = REPLACE(
description,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '/', -2),
'.',
'1'
),
REPLACE(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '/', -2),
'.',
'1'
),
' ',
'-'
)
)
WHERE
description like '%img%';